# How reliable are Flex eventListeners and BindingUtils.bindSetter

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm testing a system with a lot of clients using a Flex application. I see some unexpected behavior which looks like eventListeners or bindSetters "stop listening".

I can't seem to find on-line documentation about the reliability of those systems. Does any of you have some experience with this matter?

Let me give you one example I could solve:

**requirement**: clients need to send a command every ten seconds to the server

**implementation 1**: timer and eventListener

```
keepAliveTimer = new Timer(10000, 0);   
keepAliveTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, registerClient);
keepAliveTimer.start();
```

**problem discovered**: sometimes one or more clients stop sending that command after a random time

**implementation 2**: replace timer with enterFrame

```
 enterFrame="registerClient();"
```

**problem seems to be solved...**

Such things makes me doubt the eventListener model...

Any experience with this matter? Useful info?

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Comment: On the systems that 'stop listening' are you able to insure that the client is still running? IE No other exceptions?

Comment: As long as you don't use weak references (which you don't in the example code), event listeners are 100% "reliable". So I bet the anomaly must be elsewhere in your code. Of course I can't say much more than that without more information. Using 'enterframe' is usually not a good idea in terms of performance and timing accuracy. I never ever use it in a Flex app.

Comment: @ethrbunny yes browser is running OK

Comment: @RIAstar timing accuracy is not that important in this specific example. Thanks for the other info!

Comment: Did you check that it is actually the timer which is the problem and not the communication to the server? Try for instance to write in a shared object at each interval of timer to check that it is indeed the problem.

Comment: Your keepAliveTimer might be getting garbage collected.  Is it a class variable or a method variable?  If it's a class variable, where are you keeping a reference to that instance of the class containing the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to register and remove the listener

```
public var keepAliveTimer:Timer;

private function initVerifyClient():void
{
    keepAliveTimer = new Timer(10000, 0);   
    keepAliveTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, registerClient);
    keepAliveTimer.start();     
}

private function registerClient(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    keepAliveTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, registerClient);

    //YOUR SERVER VALIDATION CLIENT HERE

    keepAliveTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, registerClient);
}
```

Comment: when moving the define (new Timer) into the constructor of the component, it becomes reliable again... So thanks to this answer and some of the other remarks, I could improve my code. Maybe indeed it got garbaged as Brian mentioned. Thank you all!

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing. I hope everything continues to function ok.
regards